# Android FileNotFound Exception on custom.xml in the drawable-hdpi folder

Tags: android, xml, drawable, filenotfoundexception

I keep getting a FileNotFound Exception, and quite frankly, it makes no sense. Here are my files:

custom.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/easymode"></item>
```

main.xml

```
<Button android:id="@+id/guess" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:padding="20dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" 
android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
android:background="@drawable/custom"></Button>
```

I've tried moving the background tag above the others to see if that was causing it to fail, it didn't work. I've moved the custom.xml file into a drawable folder, and into the ldpi and mdpi folders but it keeps giving me the same error. Why can't it find my custom.xml when it's quite clearly there? R.java also lists it, so I know it's generated the link to it successfully... Help!

Comment: can you post your entire custom.xml? I would guess that one of your xml files is not compiling and causing the R file to not be built correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried building the R file again after saving? It can be a little confusing when working with the Android SDK in Eclipse (i'm guessing you are using Eclipse). After adding your new layout xml, are the ids for buttons and strings correctly parsed and identified in your code?

I would do a save all and then compile the project and then run it and see if this sorts your problem out.
The order of the tags makes no difference here as the layout xmls are compiled into a compact resource.

If it still cannot find the xml I suggest deleting the xml, restart Eclipse and create it again under layout, add your code above to the xml, save, compile and run and see if that sorts it out.

Comment: I cleared everything out and it's happy now, the sdk continues to confuse in the most peculiar of instances! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, there are lots of weird funnies when working with the Android SDK, one thing that will catch you initially is failing to register any new classes you added to the manifest so you add a new layout xml, add a new class, add code to handle button presses etc.. add code to start the intent for your new class from your main, then run the code in the emulator or your phone and bang it says it cannot find your new class. It is something you will need to get your head round this component style design where Android determines at runtime who is best to handle your intents. Good luck!